# Is $a_n = \frac{(-1)^nn^3}{n^3+2n^2+1}$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus

This was a question on a practice exam and the answer said the sequence was divergent, but I am confused as to why.

Determine whether the following sequence is convergent or divergent:

$$a_n = \frac{(-1)^nn^3}{n^3+2n^2+1}$$

My attempt:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(-1)^nn^3}{n^3+2n^2+1}$$

$$ = 1$$

Thus the series is convergent. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac {n^{3}} {n^{3}+2n^{2}+1} \to 1$ and $a_n$ oscillates because of the factor $(-1)^{n}$. So $\lim a_n$ does not exist.

Comment: Ah I forgot about that. You're absolutely right. Thank you!